# Config within function can't find file when executed from app.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a noob question. I'm trying to access my database using tunnel-ssh. Connecting works fine if I run the `function createTunnelToMongoDB` independently. When I run it from `app()` it returns the error `no such file or directory, open '../../id_rsa'` within config. I think the problem is to do with `model.exports`. Can someone please explain to me why I can't do it this way?

Path: `app.js`

```
(async function app() {
  try {
    // create a tunnel
    const tunnel = await createTunnelToMongoDB();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("our error", e);
  }
})();
```

Path: `createTunnelToMongoDB.js`

```
var config = {
  username: "root",
  privateKey: require("fs").readFileSync("../../id_rsa"),
  ...etc
};
var tnl = tunnel(config, function(error, tnl) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return tnl;
});

module.exports = tnl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFileSync`’s path is relative to the working directory. If you want it to be relative to the module, you have to join it with `__dirname`, the path to the directory that contains the module:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var config = {
  username: "root",
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../id_rsa")),
  ...etc
};
```